# How to find colors very close in the RGB spectrum but perceived very different by humans?

Tags: image-processing, colors, captcha, rgb

I'm trying to construct a CAPTCHA based on color similarity keeping the text color `c1` close to the background noise color `c2` in the RGB color model. But `c1` and `c2` in reality should be perceived very different by humans, so that users can read text easily but at the same time it is difficult to decode text through programming.  Is there any combination of color which is closer in all color models but in reality it is perceived different by humans?

I know I can test the similarity of colors using `delta e` concept of LAB color model. But, how to identify such colors in RGB color model systematically without hit and trial?

Comment: I am not sure if you can (without the hint and trial). This seems lik an underdetermined problem

Comment: Are you looking for a different colour space to LAB?  Or an algorithm e.g. sampling pairs of colours across RGB space, converting to LAB, and getting a ratio of delta e, to euclidean difference in RGB?

Comment: @james_alvarez Yes an efficient algorithm like that would work. But wouldn't it involve iterating through all the colors in RGB spectrum and will be computationally high?

Comment: Yes, since there are many colours (and presumably you would actually have to sample triplets).  There are many options - one possibility is you could set an rgb difference, then run a big program on all delta e's produced, then store a certain number of the best ones in a look up table with an efficient search algorithm for actualy generation of captchas.

Comment: Bear in mind though that you might see a lot of large delta e's due to differences on the lightness scale - we are much more sensitive to this than hues. I have no idea if machine's are tuned more into the dimensions too...

Comment: Also bear in mind that someone would simply have to convert the captach coordinates to LAB, before running image recognition, and the code would be cracked!

Comment: CIELAB is a good color space to check distances. To reduce your search space maybe you can confine your colors to those  `MacAdam's ellipses` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacAdam_ellipse You could use the centers of the double adjacent?? (not the adjacent one, but the one after that) ellipses  for your colors. This way you wouldnt have to search over the entire RGB color space

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find colors with [the smallest MacAdam ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacAdam_ellipse).

However, your assumption of difficulty for the CAPTCHA is incorrect. Attacker can easily convert RGB images to LAB (or similar) colorspace for processing, completely defeating the trick. For attacks based on neural networks this won't even be a speed bump, because they'll implicitly learn the required color space.

Also keep in mind that humans may not reliably see colors on screen due to viewing conditions (sunlight, low-end LCD panels) and color blindness.